# How to handle blocking calls when using reactor in a JAX-RS-powered server?

Tags: project-reactor

To process HTTP requests, we have to make blocking calls (e.g. JDBC calls) as part of a `Mono/Flux`-based process.  Our current plan looks something like this:

```java
// I renamed getSomething to processJaxrsHttpRequest
CompletionStage<String> processJaxrsHttpRequest(String input) {
  return Mono.just(input)
      .map(in -> process(in))
      .flatMap(str -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> jdbcCall(str)).subscribeOn(fixedScheduler))
      .flatMap(str -> asyncHttpCall(str))
      .flatMap(str -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> jdbcCall(str)).subscribeOn(fixedScheduler))
      .toFuture();
}
```

where `fixedScheduler` is used concurrently across HTTP requests.

We were hoping to get some feedback on this strategy for handling block calls within a decent number of fluxes.  Of course, we understand that if all our requests were flowing through these blocking calls then we might as well not use reactor (outside of the admittedly nice processing API).

Update: Thanks [bsideup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1826422/bsideup) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56706758/2071683).  However, I should have been a little more specific with my questions.

My overall question is how to effectively have a blocking call used across multiple fluxes were these fluxes can be created/subscribed to in large numbers.  We tried [the suggested approach](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking), but it results in an explosion of threads and quickly OOMs.  So we are thinking to use a shared scheduler.  So.. here are my questions.

1. Is using a shared scheduler (`fixedScheduler`) what you would suggest in the situation I describe?  If not, will you point me in any directions?
2. If using a shared scheduler is good, would this be a good implementation of it: `Schedulers.newParallel("blocking-scheduler", maxNumThreads)`?

Update 2: Just dug a big on `Schedulers#newParallel` and realize that won't work since it 'rejects' blocking calls.

Really appreciate any tips!

Comment: FYI I updated the answer with `boundedElastic` that will prevent the explosion of threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `subscribeOn` is indeed one way of handling blocking calls and your usage is okay, you can as well use `publishOn`.
It moves processing to the provided `Scheduler`, unless other `publishOn` is specified:

```java
CompletionStage<String> getSomething(String input) {
  return Mono.just(input)
      .map(in -> process(in)) // process must be non-blocking, or go after publishOn
      .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
      .map(::jdbcCall)
      .flatMap(str -> asyncHttpCall(str))
      .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
      .map(::jdbcCall)
      .toFuture();
}
```

As you can see, you can continue using async calls too. Just make sure you're not blocking non-blocking schedulers (in that example, I use `publishOn` again after `flatMap` because `asyncHttpCall` may complete from non-blocking scheduler)

Comment: Can you explain this further? Is the `jdbcCall` in your example a blocking call? I'm not quite clear how `publishOn` works so I'm not quite getting it ... but it seems the only blocking call is the `jdbcCall` since `str->asyncHttpCall` I assume is non-blocking

Comment: yes, `jdbcCall` is blocking due to JDBC's blocking nature. `publishOn` shifts execution to the provided `Scheduler`

Comment: @bsideup, are we using asynchronous and non-blocking interchangeably here? it is still a blocking call which is getting executed a dedicated thread pool right? It is async and blocking operation. I am asking this because i am confused the difference between async vs non-blocking here.